# whether....or not

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to use "or not" at the end of this sentence? I know it is not necessary but I wonder whether it could be a mistake if used it there.

Thank you.

- In the long run it is important to work on yourself regardless of whether you have set  any goal for yourself **or not**.

Comment: Yes, it's fine, and as you say, it's optional.

Comment: This [chat bookmark](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/conversation/whether-or-not) may be of interest.

Comment: Many people will actually object to leaving it out, because they feel 'whether' always contrasts exactly two things and they consider whether/or a single construction like either/or or both/and.  But most of those same folks would prefer 'whether or not you have set...' to limit the complexity of identifying the construction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use **"or not"** at the end of the sentence.

> From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whether-or-not)
>
> **Whether or not**. Also, **whether or no**.
>
> Regardless of whether, no matter if.
>
> *For example, Whether or not it rains, we're going to walk to the
>   theater, or She plans to sing at the wedding, whether or no anyone
>   asks her to.*
>
> The negative element in these constructions may also follow the
>   subject and verb, as in
>
> ***I have to attend, whether I want to or not.***

We can use 'whether... or...' as a double conjunction, with a similar meaning to 'it doesn't matter whether...or...'

***When the second part of the structure is negative, there are several possibilities:***

Whether you like it or not,...

Whether or not you like it,...

Whether you like it or whether you don't,...